# How to express type bounds on a type erased generic interface in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, type-bounds

Here is a interface defined in Java:

```java
public interface TBase<T extends TBase, F extends TFieldIdEnum>
```

When I tried to add type bounds for methods using this interface as below:

```scala
def test[TB[A <: TBase[_, _], B <: TFieldIdEnum] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
```

The error occurred:

```
type T's bounds <: TBase are stricter than type A's declared bounds <: TBase[_, _]
```

So how can I express the type bounds

```
T <: TBase
```

in Scala?

---

Additional information:

I'm using Scala 2.11.8 and the interface comes from an extremely old version of apache thrift, thrift-0.5.0

And after a lot of tries,
the only successful one until now is to remove the higher kinded type parameter:

```scala
def test[A <: TBase[_, _], B <: TFieldIdEnum](x: TBase[A, B]) = x
```

Comment: Not immediately reproducible. `javac` of `public interface TBase<T extends TBase, F> {}` and `scalac` of `object Foo {
  def test[TB[A <: TBase[_, _], B] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
}` seems to compile without errors. Where does the error come from, exactly? Also, [this here](https://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/TBase.html) has `<?, ?>`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Probably this depends on version of `libthrift`. Your link is to 0.9. In 0.12 it's `public interface TBase<T extends TBase<T,F>, F extends TFieldIdEnum> extends Comparable<T>,  TSerializable, Serializable`.

Comment: @w0mTea What are your versions of `libthrift` and Scala?

Comment: @DmytroMitin I'm using Scala 2.11.8 and an extremely old version of apache thrift, thrift-0.5.0

Comment: @w0mTea I updated my answer. With these versions I can't reproduce your error. Try `sbt clean compile`. Does `A <: TBase[A, B], B <: TFieldIdEnum` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.thrift" % "libthrift" % "0.12.0"
```

code

```
import org.apache.thrift.{TBase, TFieldIdEnum}
import scala.language.higherKinds

object App {
  def test[TB[A <: TBase[_, _], B <: TFieldIdEnum] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
}
```

produces error

```
Error:(5, 55) type arguments [A,B] do not conform to trait TBase's type parameter bounds [T <: org.apache.thrift.TBase[T,F],F <: org.apache.thrift.TFieldIdEnum]
  def test[TB[A <: TBase[_, _], B <: TFieldIdEnum] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
```

It's not exactly yours but similar.

The easiest fix is

```
  def test[TB[A <: TBase[A, B], B <: TFieldIdEnum] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
```

---

With

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
resolvers += "twitter-repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.thrift" % "libthrift" % "0.5.0"
```

I can't reproduce your error.

```
import org.apache.thrift.{TBase, TFieldIdEnum}
import scala.language.higherKinds

object App {
  def test[TB[A <: TBase[_, _], B <: TFieldIdEnum] <: TBase[A, B]](x: TB[_, _]) = x
}
```

compiles without errors.